# Is there a way to use HQL with MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mongodb, jpa

I am using MongoDB with spring-data and was wondering if this is possible. I'm looking to make my application work with MySQL at the moment and at some point in future I am planning to switch it to MongoDB. I was wondering that if I use HQL with MySQL at the moment and the switch the database to MongoDB at a later stage, will it work? If not what can I do to minimize the changes required at the later stage?

Thanks!

Comment: Switching from MySQL to MongoDB is not as easy as you might think. Both databases work very differently. To get the most of either database, you need to consider the way they work in the design stage of your application. When you want the application to use MongoDB eventually, why not develop it for MongoDB from the beginning?

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question ... is there a way to use JPA with MongoDB? obviously there is that DataNucleus JPA to name but one option. JPQL would follow from that ... but only a small subset of the operations available with RDBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL is Hibernate specific only. JPQL is a the standard JPA query language, but it doesn't support all HQL features.

Spring Data doesn't use HQL, but JPQL. You can define a Common Repository interface that can be implemented by both a MongoDB repository and a JPA one.

But querying Mongo is so much different than SQL, so you might only reuse same base CRUD operations and the standard Spring Data query translation from method names.